# Compiling TeX to txt?

Tags: conversion

So I wrote my resume in LaTeX, and I personally think it looks really good. I am currently compiling it to a PDF with lualatex. I've noticed that there are a few companies that require you to paste your resume into a text box, rather than uploading a pdf.

Is there a way to compile the document into plain text, while keeping the formatting? What I mean by "keeping the formatting" is: if I have 2 columns in the document, then the txt file will have 2 columns created by space characters. Underlined words will have underscores on the line below them, and so on. I don't have any equations in the document, so I am not concerned about the lack of formatting for that. Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: Welcome! You can't do this. You are not thinking this through. Suppose you enter 'formatted' text into their text box. What do you think it will look like by the time somebody reads it? They will not be seeing it *in that text box*. It will be parsed and combined and presented in some other way. Your spaces will no longer separate 'columns' but be randomly sprinkled. (If you're lucky, they'll delete them, but probably not.) The same will be true for your hyphen 'underlining'.  Your text will no longer make sense because line 1 of column 1 will be followed by line 1 of column 2 and so on.

Comment: You could export from a PDF viewer to text and see what you get. But as per @cfr's comment, that doesn't sound like a good idea altogether.

Comment: The reason some companies want you to upload your resume in plain-text format is that they want to be able to put the text through a lexical parser, e.g., to scan for keywords, but also to be able to detect plagiarism and other no-nos. They fully realize that plain-text and beautiful formatting are mutually incompatible. Just create a plain-text version of your cv -- save your tex file in .txt format and strip out all formatting-related instructions. Incidentally, do you really have equations in your resume? If so, you should really ask yourself what purpose they may serve in that document.

Comment: The [detex](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/detex?lang=en) utility is intended precisely for this purpose, and it comes with TeX Live. (Since it's a command-line utility, you'd open a terminal and invoke it with the command `detex file.tex > newfile.txt`.)

Unfortunately, it cannot handle math, and it doesn't handle formatting well, so I doubt it would keep two-column text. It also converts underlining, etc. to plain text, though I doubt that's a big deal for a plain text resume.

Comment: @Mico The OP explicitly says there are no equations in the resume. Also, I'm not at all sure this is why universities do it, for example. It is hard to see what they would scan for, and since lots of people have their CVs etc. on the web, they are going to get ridiculous numbers of applicants apparently plagiarising. For a statement or cover letter - just possibly, but I'd still wonder how useful it'd be - but CVs just list information. Either it is accurate or not. It doesn't matter if I got my degree the same place you did, so long as I got it.

Comment: @cfr - Please note that the "don't'" particle got edited into the posting a few minutes *after* I left my comment.

Comment: @Mico You're right, but I read it as saying there weren't any originally, just with an obvious typo making it ungrammatical. I guess you might have thought `any` a typo for `many`.

Comment: @cfr - No lexical parser is perfect, for sure. An HR office may have calibrated the parser to help catch instances of a job applicant claiming to have gone to college in country A in one document (the cover letter, say) while listing a college that's located in country B in a second document (the resume, say). Naturally, a competent human with basic knowledge of the educational institutions in countries A and B should be able to catch such discrepancies as well.